# Why doesn't setting the value property of this UISlider update its position?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uislider, ios6

...ViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
```

...ViewController.m:

```
@synthesize slider;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...
    currentValue = 50;
    self.slider.value = currentValue;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

.xib:

The UISlider in my interface is connected to the slider property.

Behavior:

The slider sits all the way to the right at value 100 when it is supposed to be in the middle. An action I set up confirms the value of currentValue is 50. If currentValue is 50 and slider.value is set to 50, why doesn't the position reflect this?

P.S. I tried [slider setNeedsDisplay] and it did not affect this behavior.

**Update:** thanks for the quick answers! What a silly thing to do. I print out currentValue as an int elsewhere so I am now setting slider.value with this code:

```
self.slider.value = (float) currentValue/100;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
currentValue = 50;
```

The slider's range is **not** 0...100 but 0...1. You have to write either

```
currentValue = 0.5;
```

or change the range of the slider:

```
self.slider.maximumValue = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Default range for UISlider is 0.0 to 1.0 (i.e. as a Float).  Setting a value above max will cause the slider to show all the way to the right.  Check your minimumValue and maximumValue properties.