# How to Dynamically change the Maximum Value of UISliders, iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have 5 UISliders. The total sum of all 5 should be 100. Now, they all start in default as 20. Therefore, they shouldn't go above 20 in the beginning, since the sum of all of them is already 100. Now, lets say I move UISlider1 and put it down to 10. This mean that now the sum between all 5 is 90, therefore I have 10 "freed up". So UISlider2 should be able to increase to 30. Or UISlider2 to 25 and UISlider3 to 25 again.

My question is, how do I do this? How do I dynamically (programatically) change the Maximum Value of a UISlider depending on the values of the others?

Thanks!

EDIT: Look at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(SOLUTION)

Thanks to everyone who replied, I figured it out on my own though and I am just going to post the solution here in case someone else needs help with it in the future.

(percent total and percentused where set to 100 as default. PercentRemaining was determined by percentotal-percentUsed. Which in the beginning is 0.)

Initialization of the slider included this:

```
slider1.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider1.maximumValue = [appDelegate getSlider1Percent] + [appDelegate   getPercentRemaining];
```

Then the slider action:
    - (IBAction)slider1Action:(UISlider *)sender
    {

```
NSUInteger value = sender.value;
self.slider1Counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%",value];



NSUInteger currentSlider1Percent = [appDelegate getSlider1Percent];
appDelegate.slider1Percent = value;


if(appDelegate.getSlider1Percent < currentSlider1Percent)
{


    nowFree = currentSlider1Percent - value;
    appDelegate.percentUsed = [appDelegate getPercentUsed] - nowFree;
    appDelegate.percentRemaining = [appDelegate getPercentTotal] - [appDelegate getPercentUsed];

    slider2.maximumValue = [appDelegate getSlider2Percent] + appDelegate.getPercentRemaining;

    slider3.maximumValue = [appDelegate getSlider3Percent] + appDelegate.getPercentRemaining;
    slider4.maximumValue = [appDelegate getSlider4Percent] + appDelegate.getPercentRemaining;
    slider5.maximumValue = [appDelegate getSlider5Percent] + appDelegate.getPercentRemaining;
}
else 
{
    nowFree = value - currentSlider1Percent;
    appDelegate.percentUsed = [appDelegate getPercentUsed] + nowFree;
    appDelegate.percentRemaining = [appDelegate getPercentTotal] - [appDelegate getPercentUsed];



    slider2.maximumValue -= nowFree;
    slider3.maximumValue -= nowFree;
    slider4.maximumValue -= nowFree;
    slider5.maximumValue -= nowFree;
}
}
```

I hope that helps some people!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
// Where you create slider
[slider1 addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[slider2 addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// ... etc.

// Somewhere else
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender{
    float total = slider1.value + ... + slider5.value;
    float delta = 100 - total;
    slider1.maximumValue = slider1.maximumValue + delta;
    slider2.maximumValue = slider2.maximumValue + delta;
    // ... etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "default" way to do this.  You are going to have to create the logic yourself.  However I will give you the three methods you need in order to have a space to execute that logic.

```
 [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderMove:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

This will make it so that it calls to your code "sliderMove."

```
 -(void)sliderMove:(UISlider*) slider
 {
    // execute logic here

 }
```

In there you will likely want to make a calls to

```
 self.slider.value = 0.x // representing percentage filled
```

to adjust slider values for whichever slider you want to move.

You should probably store all the sliders as @property from the storyboard so you can reference your values.

Setting .maximumValue will make the scale not be from 0 to 100.  See here for the difference between .value and .maximumValue.

[Why doesn't setting the value property of this UISlider update its position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322562/why-doesnt-setting-the-value-property-of-this-uislider-update-its-position)